# Extract results from CrossValidator with paramGrid in pySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I train a Random Forest with pySpark. I want to have a csv with the results, per dot in the grid.
My code is:

```
estimator = RandomForestRegressor()
evaluator = RegressionEvaluator()
paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder().addGrid(estimator.numTrees, [2,3])\
                              .addGrid(estimator.maxDepth, [2,3])\
                              .addGrid(estimator.impurity, ['variance'])\
                              .addGrid(estimator.featureSubsetStrategy, ['sqrt'])\
                              .build()
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[estimator])

crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=pipeline,
                          estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,
                          evaluator=evaluator,
                          numFolds=3)

cvModel = crossval.fit(result)
```

So I want a csv:

```
numTrees | maxDepth | impurityMeasure 

2            2          0.001 

2            3          0.00023
```

Etc

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll have to combine different bits of data:

- `Estimator` `ParamMaps` extracted using `getEstimatorParamMaps` method.
- Training metrics which can be retrieved using `avgMetrics` parameter.

First get names and values of all parameters declared in the map:

```
params = [{p.name: v for p, v in m.items()} for m in cvModel.getEstimatorParamMaps()]
```

Thane `zip` with metrics and convert to a data frame

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame.from_dict([
    {cvModel.getEvaluator().getMetricName(): metric, **ps} 
    for ps, metric in zip(params, cvModel.avgMetrics)
])
```

Comment: You must be using some outdated Python version. You can find methods which work with legacy versions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38987/8371915).

Comment: Is it possible to get the metric `accuracy` using the aforementioned procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Really helpful answer here. Thought I would extend for those using the alternative pyspark tuning class.

```
pyspark.ml.tuning.TrainValidationSplit
```

The training metrics are now retrieved using the **validationMetrics** parameter

Replacing cvModel with tvsModel (an instance of pyspark.ml.tuning.TrainValidationSplitModel) the solution becomes:

```
params = [{p.name: v for p, v in m.items()} for m in tvsModel.getEstimatorParamMaps()]

pd.DataFrame.from_dict([
    {tvsModel.getEvaluator().getMetricName(): metric, **ps} 
    for ps, metric in zip(params, tvsModel.validationMetrics)
])
```